# Converting M4A/AAC Low Profile to any other format always causes clipping... why?

Tags: audio-recording

So I'd like to send this file to my voice teacher through WhatsApp with the comfort of a play button... but converting it to any WhatsApp supported format causes the audio to be strongly clipped... why is this?

https://filebin.net/edhhx9469pcvfmci/Vincero___5_Aprile_2020_.m4a?t=re3dd6ub

Comment: Love your voice.